# How to control git which deploys to different release nos

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-actions, git-workflow

I am handling a project with a directory structure I am unaware of, instead of having project directories on the root, it is nested in `deploy/releases/108` where there are 3 other directories named 1, 106, 107 and all contain the project which I am supposed to have at root.

Below is the screenshot of directory structure;

[image: Directory structure with releases]

Here 108 is the current release number, so any changes needed to be done are in here, and I guess 1, 106, 107 are older versions, So I just wanted to know the configuration/service or app behind this structure and how I can have control over it?

While looking at logs, I found out that maybe **git** is doing this, below is the snip of the log file, But how can I know from which git account it is being done and how can I have control over it.

[image: Deploy Log File]

I can see a reference of the above log file in GitHub workflow action which ran successfully. Below is the snippet;

[image: Github workflow action]

Comment: git is not a deployment tool.  At some point in the last 10 or 15 years, it has become fashionable to (ab)use git as a deployment tool, but IT IS NOT.  Using git for deployment has always been a terrible idea.

Comment: This is what I am trying to figure out, this setup has been made by x developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, your GitHub action relies on a symlink (symbolic link) `deploy/current` referencing one of the release/xxx folders (here, `releases/107`)

Reorganise the repository in order to:

- import each releases/xxx content into a release branch
- tag each import with a release number (like tag 107)
- remove any releases/xxx folder
- add a release number as a parameter of your GitHub Action
- make said GitHub Action switch to the parameterized tag (release number)

Having folders for version/release is something I saw in the 2000's with SVN (Subversion).
This is not the Git way.